# python nested lists and for loop logic error

Tags: python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I am trying to practice python one topic at a time. Today I was learning lists and nested lists with more lists and tuples within them. I tried playing around nested lists but the program is not doing what I want it to do

Logic Error: It should print coke instead of fanta

**Code:**

```
# creating a list of products in a vending machine
products = [(1,"fanta"),(2,"coke")]

# user input
choice = input("What do you want: ")

# creates a variable 'item' that is assigned to each item in list 'products'
for item in products:
    # creates two variables for each 'item' 
    item_number, product = (item)
    if choice == "fanta" or choice == str(1):
        # deletes the item because it was chosen
        del products[0]
        # why is product fanta and not coke since fanta is deleted?
        print(product, "are still left in the machine")
```

Comment: `input()` returns a string, so `'1'` will never be equal to `1`.

Comment: And the `product` reference is not going to be updated when you execute `del products[0]`. Deleting from a list doesn't make other variables that reference other objects change.

Comment: Martijn Pieters I have fixed the string issue. Is there a way to print all of the `product` left in the list?

Comment: Sure, print the `products` list. You are not printing the list, you are printing `product` variable, set from `item` together with `item_number`.

Comment: Note that a `for` loop over a list will probably not do what you expect it to do when deleting elements. The iterator just gave the element at position `0` in the list, and will move on to the element at position `1`. Deleting the element at position `0` in the meantime, will mean that there is nothing at position `1` now (what was there has been moved to position `0` now). If you have more than 2 tuples in the list, the loop would move on to the item which was at position `2` before. This effectively skipped the element that was at position 1 at the start!

Comment: Martijn Pieters When I print the products, it looks like this: `[(2, 'coke')] are still left in the machine` but I want it to say `coke are still left in the machine`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `products` is a list, you can print the remaining items with a list comprehension:

```
print(', '.join([product[1] for product in products]), "are still left in the machine")
```

will print all remaining items in the list:

```
coke are still left in the machine
```

If you only want to remove `items` that the user enters, you don't need to iterate over `products` list, you can safely remove this line:

```
for item in products: # remove this line
```

Then, if you add more items to `products`, e.g.:

```
products = [(1,"fanta"),(2,"coke"),(3,"mt. dew")]
```

the list comprehension will print only the remaining items after deleting the users selection:

```
What do you want: 1    
coke, mt. dew are still left in the machine
```

or

```
What do you want: fanta
coke, mt. dew are still left in the machine
```

Comment: davedwards Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solution is to create a new list without the sublist.

Refer the following program and you can do easily with list comprehension and depending on the type of input value.

```
# creating a list of products in a vending machine
products = [(1,"fanta"),(2,"coke")]

# user input
choice = input("What do you want: ")

if choice.isdigit():
    print([x for x in products if int(choice) != x[0]])
else:
    print([x for x in products if choice != x[1]])
```

Output:

```
What do you want: 1
[(1, 'fanta'), (2, 'coke')]


What do you want: 1
[(2, 'coke')]

What do you want: 2
[(1, 'fanta')]

What do you want: fanta
[(2, 'coke')]

What do you want: coke
[(1, 'fanta')]
```